# Baskervaldx: error of compilation with the new update of MikTeX

Tags: packages, windows, compilation-error, miktex-update, font-metrics

This is a quick question. I wanted to change the font and to use `baskervaldx` package: https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/fonts/baskervaldx/doc/baskervaldx-doc.pdf. I have taken the same code of the pag. 3,

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[osf]{Baskervaldx} % tosf in text, tlf in math
\usepackage[vvarbb]{newtxmath} % math italic letters from Times
\usepackage[cal=boondoxo]{mathalfa} % mathcal from STIX, unslanted a bit
\usepackage{mathrsfs,graphicx,esint}
\usepackage{parskip}
\newcommand*{\starthfill}{\noindent\makebox[0pt]{}\hfill}
\newcommand*{\hfillend}{\hfill\makebox[0pt]{}}
\newcommand*{\esercizio}[1]{\par\bigskip

\noindent\textbf{Esercizio #1:}}
\newcommand*{\studente}[1]{\par\bigskip
\noindent\textbf{Studente/ssa: #1}}
\newcommand*{\riga}{\noindent\starthfill
\rule{5cm}{0.5pt}\hfillend\par}
\newcommand*{\problema}[1]{\par\bigskip
\noindent\textbf{Problema: #1}}

\begin{document} 
\esercizio{pag. 115 n. 43} 
\[\begin{split}
\cos \left(\alpha+240^{\circ \:}\right)+\sin \left(\alpha+30^{\circ \:}\right) & \\
= -\frac{1}{2}\cos \left(\alpha\right)+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sin \left(\alpha\right)+\sin \left(\alpha+30^{\circ \:}\right) & \\
= -\frac{1}{2}\cos \left(\alpha\right)+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sin \left(\alpha\right)+\sin \left(\alpha+30^{\circ \:}\right) & \\
=-\frac{1}{2}\cos \left(\alpha\right)+\frac{1}{2}\cos \left(\alpha\right)+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sin \left(\alpha\right)+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sin \left(\alpha\right) & \\
=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sin \left(\alpha\right)+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sin \left(\alpha\right) &\\
=\sqrt{3}\sin \left(\alpha\right)
\end{split}
\]


\riga

\end{document}
```

but I receive this error:

```
The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:\Users\utente\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-maketfm.log

! Font T1/Baskervaldx-TOsF/m/n/12=Baskervaldx-Reg-tosf-t1 at 12.0pt not loadabl
e: Metric (TFM) file not found.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.24 \begin{document}
                     
?
```

> What are the possible solution and why I have this error?

*PS: I have the newest updating of MikTeX of 1-8-2021.*

### Addendum:

If I take the MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[osf]{Baskervaldx} % tosf in text, tlf in math
\usepackage[vvarbb]{newtxmath} % math italic letters from Times
\usepackage[cal=boondoxo]{mathalfa} % mathcal from STIX, unslanted a bit
\usepackage{mathrsfs,graphicx,esint}
\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document} 
Start $P(x)=xa^2+bc$
\end{document}
```

I have the same problem.

[image]

### Addendum 2

[image]

Comment: No problem with a fully updated TeX Live. By the way, none of the `\left` and `\right` command is useful in that context and the alignments are dubious.

Comment: @egreg I have used symbolab math solver https://www.symbolab.com/ to be fast to solve some equations to give tomorrow in Google Suite to my students because here I have not the scanner :-(. I never write in LaTeX in this way.

Comment: Just FYI: I just tested it on Overleaf (just "copy & paste" your code). No error - it worked.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner But not to me :-(. But peraphs should I download and install the tfm metric package? http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/fonts/baskervaldx/tfm/

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I'm scarce in English and in LaTeX :-). I think that the problem it is the metric of the font Baskervaldx that it is not put in MikTeX console for windows. I have not found the solution. :-(

Comment: Sadly I am no expert on fonts (I try to stay away from the font topic). But you can give it a quick try and just copy the files on the working directory of your main file (not sure if that works).

Comment: Or maybe don't change the font and keep the "old" version. You must decide if it's important enough for you to solve the problem :). Maybe try to solve it when you have less time pressure.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I have understood very well your solution. I put into the same folder where I have the file all the tfm. :-(. But one to one because now I not find the .zip file.

Comment: I switched from MikTeX to TeXLive after similar problems about a year ago.

Comment: I meant to put it in the folder of your "main.tex" file (unzipped).

Comment: do you mean you got the package from ctan?? that should almost never be necessary, presumably this packages is in miktex so you should install it via the miktex package manager then it should install the fonts in the right place.

Comment: You are in luck :). @DavidCarlisle is now involved.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Hi David. And thank you very much for your advice. Yes I have thought to download the package from ctan. http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/fonts/baskervaldx.zip. I not remember the question of Ulrike as I can "install it via the miktex package manager then it should install the fonts in the right place".

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think that with MikTeX console must to do the old procedure changed the updmap.tex :-(. There is my old question. Thank you very much.

Comment: doing it by hand seems odd but obviously if you do, you will need the latex package and the  tfm fonts and the type1 (pfb) fonts and the map files, it is not at all clear what you have installed so far, but the whole point of a distribution like miktex or texlive is that you do not have to do this. if the miktex package install hasn't installed a working package file a bug with miktex

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have found the solution :-) Now it works perfectly!

Comment: OK glad it works, self answer if you think it is generally useful, or delete if not:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It is a packaging bug. I reported it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a packaging bug. I reported it to the miktex issue tracker:

https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/215

It should be resolved soon.

Comment: Great Fischer! :-)...and thank you very much to have open the miktex issue. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the question with the help of the very nice users (see the comments). I have put, quickly, all the files into the same folder where I have the file `.tex` and all works perfectly. See the image and the output.

[image]

[image]

...and zac.or puff..I have the output....:-)

[image]